# Gon Plugin not refreshing - Rails 4 Partial is not refreshing when using a Find

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I was using this tutorial here to integrate dropzonejs into my rails app: http://geekhmer.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/ruby-on-rails-uploads-multiple-files-with-dropzonejs-and-paperclip-gem/

It works as is, and if when I reference it from another controller (cars) it works as is. The trouble is I want it display only images that match the car id of the current car. I have the car.id all set to match the car_id field of the images table, the upload from the dropzonejs field adds it to the DB and works just fine, but when I try to filter the partial at all I can't get it to refresh when adding new images.

I have 2 controllers I'm testing this on. Images:

```
    class ImagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @images = Image.all
  end

  def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)

    if @image.save
      render json: { message: "success", fileID: @image.id }, :status => 200
    else
      render json: { error: @image.errors.full_messages.join(',')}, :status => 400
    end     
  end

private

  def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:avatar, :car_id)
  end

end
```

The Car Controller is:

```
 class CarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_car, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :load_images

  # GET /cars
  # GET /cars.json
  def index
    @cars = Car.all
  end

  # GET /cars/1
  # GET /cars/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /cars/new
  def new
    @car = Car.new
  end

  # GET /cars/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /cars
  # POST /cars.json
  def create
    @car = Car.new(car_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @car.save
        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @car }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /cars/1
  # PATCH/PUT /cars/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @car.update(car_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @car }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cars/1
  # DELETE /cars/1.json
  def destroy
    @car.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cars_url, notice: 'Car was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_car
      @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    end

    def load_images
      @images = Image.all
      @image = Image.new 
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def car_params
      params.require(:car).permit(:name, :model, :carpic)
    end
end
```

Here is the Show view I'm using from cars/show.html.erb

```
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

    <p>
      <strong>Name:</strong>
      <%= @car.name %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Model:</strong>
      <%= @car.model %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Carpic:</strong>
     <%= image_tag @car.carpic(:medium)%>
    </p>
    <h1>My Images</h1>
    <%= form_for(Image.new, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone"}) do |f|  %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :car_id, :value => @car.id %>
      <div class="fallback">
        <%= f.file_field :avatar %><br>
        <%= f.submit "Upload my Avatar" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="index">
      <%= render partial: 'images/index' %>
    </div>

    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_car_path(@car) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', cars_path %>

Here is the partial images/_index.html.erb
<% @images.each do |image| %>
        <div class="img-thumbnail"><%= image_tag image.avatar.url(:thumb), alt: image.avatar.url(:thumb) %></div>
<% end %>
```

Here is app/assets/javascripts/image.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // disable auto discover
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

  var dropzone = new Dropzone (".dropzone", {
    maxFilesize: 256, // set the maximum file size to 256 MB
    paramName: "image[avatar]", // Rails expects the file upload to be something like model[field_name]
    addRemoveLinks: false // don't show remove links on dropzone itself.
  });

  dropzone.on("success", function(file) {
    this.removeFile(file);
    $.getScript("/images");
  })
});
```

and here is views/images/index.js.erb

```
$(".index").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('index')) %>")
```

Again this works if I don't try to filter the results of @images in the partial to only display image.car_id. It displays them but it doesn't refresh when dropzonejs uploads the file like when doesn't have the filter on.

I've tried this in the partial _index

```
<% Image.where(car_id: @car.id).find_each do |image| %>
    <div class="img-thumbnail">
      <%= image_tag image.avatar.url(:thumb), alt: image.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Again, this works but it doesn't refresh like when it it's not being filtered. I have played around in the controller with no success either.

Also, I have the relationships setup right, images belongs to cars, cars has many images.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Been trying to this together for a week!

EDITED TO ADD BELOW

So I've been able to get this to work with the GON gem, but have a new problem, here is my code below:

the Show Controller, I've added:

```
def show
    gon.watch.carid = @car.id
  end
```

To the top of the includes in application.html.erb I've added:

```
 <%= include_gon(:watch => true, :init => true) %>
```

My Image.js file now looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

// disable auto discover
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

```
  var dropzone = new Dropzone (".dropzone", {
    maxFilesize: 256, // set the maximum file size to 256 MB
    paramName: "image[avatar]", // Rails expects the file upload to be something like model[field_name]
    addRemoveLinks: false // don't show remove links on dropzone itself.
  });

  dropzone.on("success", function(file) {
    this.removeFile(file);
    $.getScript(gon.watch.carid);
  })
});
```

So here's the new problem, if I'm adding images to car.id"1" then go back to the car index and click the show link for the car.id"2" when I add the new image via the drop zone the cars in the gallery from car.id"2" switches to the car.id"1" until I click refresh on the page, it then resets the variable in gon.watch.carid.

I assumed, apparently incorrectly that calling the show method to display the second car should reset that gon variable? if not the gon watch and init call in the application.html.erb file I thought should do it.

Has anyone worked with Gon or have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by moving the gon include statement from the head to the body of the application.html.erb file, all is fine now!

Hopefully this helps someone else!

d